# AS3 Simple way to check if sound is finished

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a sound that plays whenever I rollover an object. To make it less annoying I want the sound to play only if it's not playing already. Since I need this with a couple of different sounds I don't want to use a timer (if not absolutely necessary). I found this:

```
var channel:SoundChannel = snd.play(); 
channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete); 

public function onPlaybackComplete(event:Event) 
{ 
    trace("The sound has finished playing."); 
}
```

but I'm not sure I can use it since I have a background music as well. Any tips?

Comment: If you need to manage with several sounds that's time to think about some centralized approach like sound manager - to have global sound on/off, control over several sounds/the same sound, etc. There are many of them https://github.com/treefortress/SoundAS, http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2011/01/06/as3/as3-soundmanager-v1-4/, google _as3 sound mananer_ for more

Answer (score 1):

You can use such a trick selectively. Still, if you plan to have a lot of such objects that trigger sounds on mouse-overs, you might decide to have a manager class or data table that would have an entry per such an object, and its field would have a true if the sound is played, and a listener assigned as such would clear the value in that field, deriving the correct entry from registered set of `SoundChannel`s. A premade sound manager would do, but you'd better make a tailored one. An example:

```
public class SoundManager {
    private var _fhOPO:Dictionary; 
    private var _bhOPO:Dictionary; 
    // going sophisticated. Names stand for "forward hash once per object" and "backward"
    // forward hash stores links to SoundChannel object, backward stores link to object from
    // a SoundChannel object.
    // initialization code skipped
    public static function psOPO(snd:Sound,ob:Object):void 
    {
        // platy sound once per object
        if (_fhOPO[ob]) return; // sound is being played
        var sc:SoundChannel=snd.play();
        _fhOPO[ob]=sc;
        _bhOPO[sc]=ob;
        sc.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, _cleanup);
    }
    private static function _cleanup(e:Event):void 
    {
        var sc:SoundChannel=event.target as SoundChannel;
        if (!sc) return; // error handling
        var ob:Object=_bhOPO[sc];
        _bhOPO[sc]=null;
        _fhOPO[ob]=null; // clean hashes off now obsolete references
        sc.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, _cleanup); 
        // and clean the listener to let GC collect the SoundChannel object
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need to play a sound but limit to one instance of channel per object, you call `SoundManager.psOPO(theSound,this);` providing a button reference instead of `this` if need be. You can use normal `Sound.play()` alongside this kind of sound management should you need to, or use another type of management for BGM or other types of sounds should you need to.